# Spike detection in time series using Artificial Neural Networks

Tags: deep-learning, long-short-term-memory, prediction, time-series

I'm quite new in ANNs. I intend to use ANNs for predicting spike points in time series right before they happen. I've already used LSTM for another scenario, and I know that they can be used in similar situations as well.

Can anyone give me a piece of advice or some suitable resources that might be used as a beginning point? It would be much appreciated if it uses [DeepLearning4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/) for implementation.

Comment: Since you mentioned that you have already used LSTMs I can directly guide you to using it for time Series prediction.
For detailed description you can check the following link: <https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-analysis-visualization-forecasting-with-lstm-77a905180eba> This is a very useful article for you to grasp the idea behind time Series Prediction.
I suggest you go through this to get an idea and then try implementing this in dl4j.

Comment: What kind of time series data is it? Do you happen to have covariates? What is the sampling interval of the data? How big is the data -- i mean number of data points? Multivariate..?